# How to use props to hold user fed input (via textbox) in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and I want to know if there is anyway to make props hold user fed input strings (fed from textbox).

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from your question is that you just want to store the value of user input Which has been input by the user.
So the best way to hold it is to make a state which will keep track of it.Since user input might change so it's better to store in a state rather than props.

So Here is the simple implementation which can give the idea how to do this.

```
import React from "react";

export default class Bind extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            value:''
        }
        this.onChangeInput=this.onChangeInput.bind(this)
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="well">
                    <input onChange={this.onChangeInput}/><br/>
                    <cite>{this.state.value}</cite>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    onChangeInput(event){
        this.setState({
            value:event.target.value
        });

    }
}
```

Actually, in this Component, we have initialized a state with empty value and in our render method where our input field lies I have used the change event which calls some function.and in that function we have just updated our state by using `value: event.target.value`

I hope this makes sense to you, again I will say better to use state in place of props here props are just to pass some data to be used in the component and it is immutable but the state is something which changes and can hold the values and thus by using that our view changes.